# Different Folder Structure from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm building an app which requires the frontend and the api to be separate. The folder looks like this

```
application/
.git/
frontend/
api/
Procfile
```

The API is a rails application so I'd like to use the cedar stack from Heroku.

When I try and push the application I get the message

```
!     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

Which makes sense as it needs to look in a subfolder. How do I tell heroku to only use the sub folder?

Answer (score 0):

The folder structure you posted doesn't look like a Rails app at all.

If you want to split the frontend from the api, you can perfectly to that at controller level by having two different namespaces.

That will generate a structure like the following one

```
app/
  controllers/
    api/
      whatever_controller.rb
    frontend/
      user_controller.rb
      whatever_controller.rb
public/
log/
db/
Procfile
... other standard Rails folders and files
```

The structure you have seems to represent two completely different Rails app. If that's the case, then you need to use two different Heroku app.

If that's not the case, then that could not work. I don't even think how you can start it, given that it doesn't represent a standard Rails structure.

Comment: The rails app lives inside of the API folder

Comment: Then, as I said, they are two apps. You need to deploy two different Heroku apps.

Comment: Simone - You can use git subtree. I'll post the answer once I've got it working!